# SGX error while booting kubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, uefi

I had updated Win 10 to Win 11 on 9th Oct, and dual booted Kubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on 16th oct but unfortunately on 15th Nov, exactly 30 days later Kubuntu fails to boot up and shows "SGX disabled by BIOS". I am 100% sure that I did not mess around with any of the boot files or any other root directories, and neither did I make any change to the BIOS, so I don't understand why did this error pop up, but Win 11 works fine..., is there a way to fix it ?? Please help.
P.S I have Secure boot On, Fast boot On, Intel RST on and on UEFI mode.